# Page not rendering when flask call is pushed with render after file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, python-2.7, flask

Problem :

Iam having a file upload page(Code below) where there is an option to upload file and file when uploaded triggers post request `/uploadFiles1` and it is handled by flask ( Code below) after this it triggers series of event on the file and after all the activities are finished i want to display a message `Success in the same page`.But it is not displaying.

**flask_app.py**

```
@app.route("/uploadFiles")
def index():
        return render_template('upload.htm') , 1
@app.route('/uploadFiles1', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':

                f = request.files['file']
                if f:
                        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
                        f.save( os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename ))
                        copyfile(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename) ,os.path.join('/home/admin/Batch/Samples/', filename))
                        # Call the remote function
                        from paramiko import SSHClient
                        client = SSHClient()
                        client.load_system_host_keys()
                        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                        client.connect("192.168.90.90", username="nsadmin",password='something')
                        transport = client.get_transport()
                        #stdin , stdout , stderr =client.exec_command('sudo ls')
                        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sudo python /home/nsadmin/app.py')
                        print "stderr: ", stderr.readlines()
                        print "Output: ", stdout.readlines()
                        # Remove this file from /Batch/Samples/ Location
                        #os.remove(os.path.join('/home/admin/Batch/Samples/', filename))
                        print 'I came here'
                        msg = 'File upload Success'
                        logger.info('I came here with msg {}'.format(msg))
                        return render_template('upload.htm', msg=msg) , 1
```

**upload.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload </title>
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >

<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Upload Malware Here</h1>
<h3>
{% if msg %}
    {{ msg }} #empty page
  {% endif %}
</h3>
<div class="upload">
                        <h3>Select File</h3>
                <div class="login-form">
                        <form id="upload" method="POST" action="/uploadFiles1"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div id="drop">
                                <a>Upload</a>
                                <input type="file" name="file" />
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="submit">


                                <ul>
                                <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
                                </ul>

                        </form>
                </div>

</div>
<!-- JavaScript Includes -->
                <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.knob.js') }}"></script>
        <!-- JavaScript Includes -->

        <!-- jQuery File Upload Dependencies -->
                <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.ui.widget.js') }}"></script>
                <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.iframe-transport.js') }}"></script>
                <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.fileupload.js') }}"></script>
        <!-- jQuery File Upload Dependencies -->

        <!-- Main JavaScript file -->
           <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
        <!-- Main JavaScript file -- >



</body>
</html>
```

**script file**

```
root@corpus:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp# cat static/js/script.js
$(function(){

    var ul = $('#upload ul');

    $('#drop a').click(function(){
        // Simulate a click on the file input button
        // to show the file browser dialog
        $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
    $('#upload').fileupload({

        // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
        dropZone: $('#drop'),

        // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
        // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
        add: function (e, data) {

            var tpl = $('<li class="working"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
                ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');

            // Append the file name and file size
            tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                         .append('<i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

            // Add the HTML to the UL element
            data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

            // Initialize the knob plugin
            tpl.find('input').knob();

            // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
            tpl.find('span').click(function(){

                if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                    jqXHR.abort();
                }

                tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                    tpl.remove();
                });

            });

            // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
            var jqXHR = data.submit();
        },

        progress: function(e, data){

            // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

            // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
            // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
            data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

            if(progress == 100){
                data.context.removeClass('working');
            }
        },

        fail:function(e, data){
            // Something has gone wrong!
            data.context.addClass('error');
        }

    });


    // Prevent the default action when a file is dropped on the window
    $(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Helper function that formats the file sizes
    function formatFileSize(bytes) {
        if (typeof bytes !== 'number') {
            return '';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
        }

        return (bytes / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
    }

});
```

Solution I tried :

I created a placeholder in the html page and after all the processing i rendered the page again with the msg.But it is not reprsehing with the msg.

Any suggestions will help
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Response is populating but page is not updating with  element.

[image]

Comment: I would start by using Chrome's developer tools to look at the source of the rendered success page. See what's happening to the `<h3>` block where your message should go. Putting the full output into a [gist](https://gist.github.com) would also be helpful to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Javascript to upload the file via an XHR, rather than doing a full POST request with your browser:

```
// Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
 var jqXHR = data.submit();
```

That means that the rendered response is being sent back to your Javascript, which ignores it.

You've got two options:

1. Do a standard POST by disabling the Javascript upload and having the user submit the full form, in which case your message should render properly.
2. Have the Javascript check for success and render a message itself.